# Add Null Values into Table, where there is a missing spot in a row of values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with how much time it took for a person to wait for the train from the moment they arrived until the train came. I want to say how many persons had to wait from 0 to 10 ms, 10 - 20 ms, and so on. I have a table with all these data. My problem is, if there is no person who had to wait between 0 and 10 ms i would want it to still be there in the table with the value 0, but I want to write a query in which this is done automatically, to detect where is a gap and create a time interval and fill it.
I have written an SQL query for it, to get the information I want, but some time intervals are missing. It looks like this:

```
SELECT (p2.TimeMs - p1.TimeMs)/(1000*10)+1 AS TimeBucket, COUNT(p2.Passenger - p1.Passenger) AS Separated
FROM Passenger p1 
JOIN Passenger p2 ON p1.passenger = p2.passenger
WHERE p1.Event= 0 AND p2.Event= 1 //0 is for arriving at the station and 1 is for the ending of the waiting time
GROUP BY TimeBucket ORDER BY TimeBucket;
```

Comment: @TheImpaler "null value" is perfectly fine, how else do you want to call them?. Docs of every major relational database engine refers to them as such

Comment: @Lamak Sigh. Just call them "nulls". It's just is confusing to call them "values" in SQL. They are values in Java, C, C#, and other programming languages, however. And... I don't want to start a religious war here. I'll remove the comment.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @TheImpaler: for what it's worth: the SQL standard refers to that as "null value" as well.

Comment: You could construct a table of the buckets required a perform a left join with your query above.

Comment: @JohnnyFitz thank you a lot! this sounds like a great idea :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this I think. You would need to replace the temp table declaration with a the SQL Lite equivalent. Also you may need to cast your values to decimals where for instance if p2.TimeMs - p1.TimeMs < 10000 you would get zero returned if the data is stored as integers.

```
declare @buckets table 
(
BucketID int
TimeBucket int,
BucketDesc varchar(50)
)

insert @buckets(bucket) 
values(1,10,'0-10'), 
--....all values - could populate other values using distinct set of buckets from below 

select A.TimeBucket, B.* 
from @buckets B 
left join 
(
    SELECT (p2.TimeMs - p1.TimeMs)/(1000*10)+1 AS TimeBucket, COUNT(p2.Passenger - p1.Passenger) AS Separated
    FROM Passenger p1 
    JOIN Passenger p2 ON p1.passenger = p2.passenger
    WHERE p1.Event= 0 AND p2.Event= 1 //0 is for arriving at the station and 1 is for the ending of the waiting time
    GROUP BY TimeBucket
) D
on B.TimeBucket = D.TimeBucket
```